# Access php variables in python

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a apache server running program which has the live update of several variables. I need to access them to manipulate the data in my python program. How do i do that ?.

I was using the php file directly by using shell commands to execute the direct python command. But now since i upgraded i need to replace it with variables and i want to use the data provided by the php file to be in main.py to manipulate the result from the data received.

For eg:

PHP file:

```
<?php
$a = 200;
?>
```

Python file:

```
b=40000  
c=a+b // the value of c should be imported from the php file  
print c
```

now how do i import this value of 'a' from php

Comment: You should improve the question otherwise it's too hard to answer. So there's a PHP program running from apache, when a request comes in there's some variable that gets updated? Does it persist in between requests somehow? If so, how is that done?

In general you'd have to write the data into a backend database or some other kind of store so you can get to it from another process. Or potentially use some kind of IPC like a named pipe but that's less common.

Comment: What kind of python file is that supposed to be?

Comment: @jambox  the php file keeps getting data when a button is toggled, ie 1 for toggled on and 0 for toggled off. this 1 and 0 of the variable keeps updating infinite time. i want the variable`s value in my main.py which uses the value to get a result by passing in some conditional clauses. this result is to be used to turn the GPIO of the raspberry pi on or off.

Comment: @mrCarnivore this python file is used to drive the GPIO pin of the raspberry pi

Comment: Will the python program be running as a daemon then? If so you can probably just put the value into a file and have the python daemon check the contents every second or whatever. It's hacky but it would work.

Comment: @jambox how do i get the value of php in a file. yeah i am using daemon

Comment: Not trying to be rude but you can easily google how to write out to a file into php.

Comment: @jambox that wont work i guess.. coz i need to access the file in both php and python

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it's hard to say what the *best* answer is, but here are some options:

Option 1:
Forget about python, do your logic in php

Option 2:
Use shell_exec to execute your python from php and pass your variables as arguments, like this:

```
<?php
$a = 200;
shell_exec("example.py $a");
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

If all you're doing with the python program is toggling the GPIO, skip the python and use the 'gpio' tool http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/

Comment: will this command update the value of the variable a in my python file ?

Comment: that depends on what's in 'example.py'.  You can't share variables between php and python unless you use some sort of structured exchange.  IPC was proposed in a comment on your question, but typically IPC is used between different threads of the same program.  In your case IPC is unlikely to be feasible.  You're probably better off using something like a database, API, or a message queue.

Comment: what kind of a database do u suggest. there are like 14 variables which are to be updated constantly. which database can actually be used for both python and php .

Comment: People use redis or memcached as a way of sharing data between services but OTOH some would say "db is not supposed to be IPC".

Comment: Any of them can be used for python and php afaik.  If they're updated *constantly* you might be better off with something like a message queue or memcached.  it really all depends on what you're trying to do and how much overhead you can afford.

Comment: @smokes2345 if i try your program, the shell_exec function doesn`t operate. it just displays the whole program when i open it in browser

Comment: @Shyam you may need to use the full path.  Also, make sure your shebang is correct in the python script.  If you're running on RHEL you may also need to correct the SELinux context.

Comment: @smokes2345 i used the full path there.. here it is      <?php
$a = 200;
shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/html/ one.py;");
?>  i even tried it with sudo still no response. I am running Raspbian os

Comment: You're using the full path to the script, but not the full path to sudo.  In your example 'shell_exec' is calling sudo, not your script.  Also, if your shebang is correct you don't need to include 'python'.  When you say 'displays the whole program' do you mean it displays the python code or the 'shell_exec' line?

Comment: it show the shell _exec line. how do i get to know the path of sudo

Comment: @smokes2345 wiringpi allows me only to toggle. i am using the data from some pins and passing it to some conditions then if the condition is true some other gpio will turn on or off according to the condition.